# Scala: Syntax causing runtime error?

Tags: scala, syntax, semantics

I am learning Scala and trying to write some command line executables.

I have two version of HelloWorld, which I thought were semantically the same. `HelloWorld.scala` compiles and runs successfully from the command line. `HelloWorld2.scala` compiles but produces a runtime error.

My Question: I would think that the two would be semantically the same, so why does the second one produce a runtime error?

Here's the working example:

```scala
// HelloWorld.scala

object HelloWorld {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello, World!")
  }
}
```

Here's the broken example:

```scala
// HelloWorld2.scala

object HelloWorld2 {

  def main
    : Array[String] => Unit
    = args          => {
      println("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

Here's the console output:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: HelloWorld2.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1778)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: It is looking for `HelloWorld2.main` but you only have `HelloWorld.main`. Try either changing the class name to match the file, or changing the file name to match the class (i.e. copy the code in your broken example into HelloWord.scala)

Comment: You have two different things here: a `main` method which takes an `Array[String]` and has return type `Unit`, versus a `main` method which takes no arguments and returns a function that takes an `Array[String]` and has return type `Unit`.

Comment: @TheDark, Thank you for pointing out the object name. TBH, that was just a typo in my question: the actual files I was working with named the object correctly.

Comment: @Jesper, I had never in my wildest imagination considered that a method and a function where not the same thing ^_^;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless that scala can convert a method to a function (with eta-expansion, sometimes automatical), they're [different things](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html) here. The major difference is that scala generates a different bytecode for JVM.

Talking about your example, you actually defined a method `def` that returns an object of class [`Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/rc2/scala/Function1.html):

```
def main: Function1[Array[String], Unit] //you could even put `val` here
```

when JVM requires a method with completely different signature:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit
```

Because for JVM a function is just an instance of a class `FunctionN`, scala-compiler doesn't convert it to a method automatically. Manual conversion would look like:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = main.apply(args)

def main: Array[String] => Unit = ...// or `val main`
```

Note that `apply` is just a method of `Function1` class, `()` is just a syntax sugar for calling `apply`.

Update:

Just an additional information. As @som-snytt pointed out, `scala`s runner is more flexible about `main`'s signature, so this:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Int
```

will work for `scala HelloWorld`, but won't work for `java HelloWorld` - it will require `Unit` (`void`) as a return type. I can also recall some differences between compiling Java-code with `javac` vs `scalac`. So the point is that `scala`/`scalac` is evolving, so it might be possible (in future) for `scala` to run more relaxed `main` methods, like maybe functional interfaces or something. It can also compile and run scripts, btw.

Comment: Just `java` requires that sig. Define `def main(args: Array[String]): Int` and you'll see a stern warning, but `scala` will run it. Scala could be much more flexible. It would be nice if it printed the result value by default. Also, thx for the doc link.

Comment: Thank you very much for the spot-on answer and clear explanation. I've been trying to write my Scala decidedly un-idiomatically, writing out everything's type signature on a separate line. Unfortunately, it seems I'll have to stop doing that.